# RecyclerView expanding item with ConstraintSet - expands wrong item/row

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-constraintlayout

I have a RecyclerView and want to expand rows with ConstraintSet's.
The RecyclerView part works and the general idea of expanding/collapsing with ConstraintSet works too, but it expands the wrong row.
If I click on the first entry it expands some item like 10 rows below it.

Since I'm new in using RecyclerView and ConstraintSet, I'm a little flustered on how to solve it.
My Adapter code looks like this:

```
public class ProgressAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProgressAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<ProgressData> progressData;

    private ConstraintSet collapsedConstraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
    private ConstraintSet expandedConstraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
    private ConstraintLayout mainLayout;
    private boolean expanded = false;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView t1;
        ...

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            t1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.t1text);
            ...

        }
    }

    public ProgressAdapter(List<ProgressData> progressData) {
        this.progressData = progressData;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ProgressAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View progressView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.progress_item, parent, false);
        mainLayout = (ConstraintLayout) progressView;

        collapsedConstraintSet.clone(mainLayout);
        expandedConstraintSet.clone(mainLayout.getContext(), R.layout.progress_item_expanded);

        mainLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(mainLayout);
                if (expanded) {
                    collapsedConstraintSet.applyTo(mainLayout);
                    expanded = false;
                } else {
                    expandedConstraintSet.applyTo(mainLayout);
                    expanded = true;
                }
            }
        });

        return new MyViewHolder(progressView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ProgressAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        ProgressData progress = progressData.get(position);
        holder.t1.setText(progress.getNumber());
        ...

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return progressData.size();
    }

}
```

The outcome doesn't change, regardless where I put the ClickListener (where it is now, or in the ViewHolder or in the onBind).
When I Log `mainLayout.getId()` it's always `-1`, maybe that's part of the problem?
I just don't really get how I pass the Id or whatever else from the clicked row to my `applyTo`, or maybe I'm already doing that somehow?! Like I said, it's all new to me and I dove right into the deep end here.

I hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: put recyclerview inside nestedscrollview.

Comment: Thanks, but I just tried that and it didn't really change anything. Only thing that changed is, that now the row that gets expanded is even further down in the line.

Comment: @IntersectGlasses Those work because the variables that holds the `ConstraintLayout` are view holder member variables, so each view holder gets its own copy. You have just one global copy since your `mainLayout` is not in the view holder but adapter..

Comment: @Cheticamp Oh wow, first of all, thanks for even answering that second question (I would love to give you another checkmark :) ), second of all, I just put everything in my viewholder and it even works better now! Now I can expand as many items as I want (already thought of how I could acomplish that otherwise with stuff like "lastId" or somethiing) and lastly, how didn't I see that on my own? I guess proper indentation is crucial sometimes :) Thanks for the third time :P You totally made my day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the class member variable `mainLayout` to expand and collapse your views. The problem is that this variable will contain a reference to the latest view holder created and not the one that was clicked.

I think a quick fix to this would be to change your click listener as follows to apply the `ConstraintSet` to the clicked view:

```
mainLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(mainLayout);
            if (expanded) {
                collapsedConstraintSet.applyTo((ConstraintLayout) view);
                expanded = false;
            } else {
                expandedConstraintSet.applyTo((ConstraintLayout) view);
                expanded = true;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Ha, it works! Thank you so much! I still don't get how it works in the [Google I/O App from 2017](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/e4364eec0d8f358215aee30cce2b4836ec169b5a/lib/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/feed/FeedViewHolder.java) or [here](https://github.com/queencodemonkey/presentation-cool-constraintlayout/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/randomlytyping/ccl/ListItemActivity.kt), because they seem much "cleaner", but I'm okay with that I guess :) Thanks again!

Comment: I've followed what you did here, but the view doesn't animate. It just snaps from it's original position to it's end position without animating. Am I missing something?